# hide pages in websphere portal without using set parameters

Tags: portal, websphere-portal

I am using WebSphere Portal 8.5 Enable. I have created a custom theme. But this theme requires to hide pages on navigation which has unique name with ".omit." value in it, so that I don't have to manually set each page's parameter.
I created the flyout or menu dropdown using this:
[Flyout or Menu Dropdown in Portal 8 themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591151/flyout-or-menu-dropdown-in-portal-8-themes)
Any suggestions and pointers are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have already thought about this.

The solution you mentioned ([Flyout or Menu Dropdown in Portal 8 themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591151/flyout-or-menu-dropdown-in-portal-8-themes)) hides nodes based on the hidden flag. This method is used to calculate it. Now you could query the uniquename of the Node witin this method and check for your naming pattern and use this to determine if it is hidden. It would allow you to combine the two as well.

the method I think you need to modify.

```
public boolean isHiddenPage(NavigationNode node){
    if (node instanceof com.ibm.portal.MetaDataProvider) {
        com.ibm.portal.MetaData iMetaData=((com.ibm.portal.MetaDataProvider) node).getMetaData();
        Object url=iMetaData.getValue("hide.from.menu");
        return (url != null && url.toString().equals("true"));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide any page using the role settings just create a user group which is never used and make that the only thing that can access the page. You should be able to do this is your PAA's PageAssignAccessControl.xml (could be slightly wrong about the name of this file) as well as in the portal Admin console, so you can do it automatically in your deployment code.

Comment: I need to hide the pages from navigation pane but when users click on an image they should be redirected to that page will this do that?  thanks for d reply :)

Comment: Also shed more light on "do it automatically in your deployment code"

Comment: Hi Rue, you should be able to hide pages from the navigation with portal user roles. By do it automatically in your deployment code, I mean that you can have xmlaccess code in your PAA which defines what user roles have access to pages and portlets.

Have a look around here:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.5.0/admin-system/resources_roles.html?lang=en

might be of some use to you